# Correct root class for Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I've found references online that talk about two different root classes for ObjC, either `objc/Object.h` or `Foundation/NSObject.h`. They require different compiler flags (`-lobj` vs. `-lobjc -framework Foundation`, and have different selectors for initializing & releasing objects. Is NSObject a replacement, or do they have different applications? Obviously `NSObject.h` would be better for NextStep-type stuff, but does `Object.h` have advantages that would make it better in certain situations?

FWIW, the [updated FAQ](http://www.thaesofereode.info/clocFAQ/#cocoa-root) from comp.lang.objective-c seems to indicate the `NSObject.h` is correct; an [older version](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/computer-lang/Objective-C/faq/) mentions `Object.h`

Comment: in Objective-C, one can make new root classes, simply by defining a class without a superclass. Hence, it is okay to have multiple root classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding of the situation is there are two runtime libraries for Objective-C. Apple's library, which uses NSObject, and the GNU library which uses Object. If you are developing for an Apple platform, use their runtime. If you're developing for a non-Apple platform, you use the other.